# Cannot start docker image of zabbix-server-mysql: Keep showing "MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds..."

Tags: mysql, docker, ssl, zabbix

I cannot start docker image of zabbix-server-mysql.  It keeps showing "MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds..."

Detail:

```
docker pull zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-5.2-latest
docker run --name zabbix-server -e DB_SERVER_HOST="xxxxx" -e MYSQL_USER="xxxxx" -e MYSQL_PASSWORD="xxxx" -e MYSQL_DATABASE="zabbix" -d zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-5.2-latest
docker logs -f zabbix-server
```

The logs keep showing

```
**** MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
**** MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
**** MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
```

Answer (score 0):

After study for a while, I go into the container and user the mysql cli to test the connection.   Finally, I found that it is simply the problem related to SSL.  You have to explicitly enable the SSL options if your MySQL Database only accepts connection with SSL (TLS):
`-e ZBX_DBTLSCONNECT="required`

So

```
docker run --name zabbix-server -e DB_SERVER_HOST="xxxxx" -e MYSQL_USER="xxxxx" -e MYSQL_PASSWORD="xxxx" -e MYSQL_DATABASE="zabbix" -e ZBX_DBTLSCONNECT="required -d zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-5.2-latest
```

(For your reference, `zabbix-web` has an environment variable `ZBX_DB_ENCRYPTION="true"` for the same issue)